# how safe is UnsafeMutableRawPointer( variable )

Tags: swift, unsafemutablepointer

If i want to obtain the unsafemutablerawpointer of a variable.
Yet without creating copies or buffer, what is the best/efficient way to do so?

The below example works!

```
var number:UInt = 5

let numberPointer = UnsafeMutableRawPointer(&number)

var pointer:UnsafeMutablePointer<UInt8> = numberPointer.bindMemory(to: UInt8.self, capacity: size)

pointer[0] = 88

print(numberPointer) // 88
```

Yet from apple's docs:

[docs](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3YIDJ.png)

Comment: As you found in the Apple's doc. Your example  would seemingly work in some specific condition. Unfortunately, the condition is not documented and causes **undefined behavior**. What answer do you want? _**NO**, it is not safe._ Or some other safe way?

Comment: Yes, what other safe way that is efficient to extract an UnsafeMutableRawPointer from any variable (eg. float, int, uint, int8, etc...).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is not safe as in Apple's doc or as in my comment.

If you want to do it in some safe way, you may need to write something like this:

```
var number: UInt = 5

let size = MemoryLayout.size(ofValue: number)
withUnsafeMutableBytes(of: &number) {numberUmbp in
    let numberPointer = numberUmbp.baseAddress!
    let pointer: UnsafeMutablePointer<UInt8> = numberPointer.bindMemory(to: UInt8.self, capacity: size)

    pointer[0] = 88
} //`pointer` (or `numberPointer`) is guaranteed to be valid only inside this closure

print(number) // 88
```

Of course, the pointer `pointer` is only valid inside the closure.

If you want to extract some more stable and permanent address, you cannot avoid *creating copies or buffer*, in the current specification of Swift.